# Can not install packages from UbuntuGIS

Tags: qgis, gdal, installation, linux, ubuntugis

I recently changed my OS to Xubuntu 16.04.
Now i try to install GDAL to use it via shell and QGIS.

I followed the steps from the official UbuntuGIS website (https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ppa). While updating I can see the path for the UbuntuGIS ppa (I post the log ant the end).

Now my Questions is: Can I use UbuntuGIS under Xubuntu and if yes, what am I doing wrong?

Output of the shell while updating my ppa:

```
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make/ubuntu xenial InRelease    
Hit:2 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease  
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]                                                  
Hit:4 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease                                                                    
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                  
Hit:6 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. Do you get any error messages?

Comment: @AndreJ Maybe I did something wrong (I am new to Ubuntu). Here is my exact input in the shell: 

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa` ; 

`sudo apt-get update`; 

`sudo apt upgrade`; 

`sudo apt-get install gdal`

Comment: That looks ok so far. Do you get GDAL 2.2.1 installed, or any error message instead? BTW you should use the Ubuntugis unstable PPA: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntugis-unstable/ to get the latest GDAL version.

Comment: @AndreJ Yes, this is the output I get :                                                                      
lastro@lastro-Lenovo:~$ sudo apt-get install gdal :
Reading package lists... Done ;
Building dependency tree ;
Reading state information... Done ;
E: Unable to locate package gdal

Comment: It should be `sudo apt-get install gdal-bin`. You might try `apt-cache policy gdal-bin`  to display available versions before installing.

Comment: @AndreJ With gdal-bin I can install the package. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to use UbuntuGIS and Xubuntu. I would recommend following this tutorial [Install some stuff on Xubuntu 16.04](https://benhur07b.github.io/2017/03/28/install-some-stuff-on-ubuntu-16.04.html)

They include PPA as such:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable`

or you can add the following lines to your /etc/apt/sources.list

`deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu xenial main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu xenial main`

Comment: Thanks for the advise. It helped me a lot. Only one question: Is there a way to install the stable version of UbuntGIS? It fails, when i try to insert stable instead of unstable.

Comment: Sure thing. If this question is answered lets mark it as such and you could start a new post for the second question, that way others can see the new question as well, if that's cool.

Answer (score 1):

As per the comment by @AndreJ, use,

```
sudo apt-get install gdal-bin
```

*after* adding the UbuntuGIS repository, to install GDAL (as they also mentioned, you may want to query first for available versions).